# Identify that no chars appear in a given page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm faced with the prospect of blank pages scattered intermittently in a Word doc, which I'd like to discard.  But I need to identify them in VBA first.  There are spots in each where a caret lands if I click on the sheet.

But I don't know how to progress from there.  How to instruct Word via VBA to identify whether the sheet has content in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something on these lines may suit.

```
ActiveDocument.Repaginate
j = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)

For i = j To 1 Step -1
    NotEmpty = True
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=CStr(i)
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page"
    If Selection.Characters.Count < 3 Then
        NotEmpty = False
        For Each c In Selection.Characters
            If Asc(c) > 13 Then
                ''Possibly not empty
                NotEmpty = True
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If NotEmpty = False Then
        Selection.Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That's quite incredible, Remou.  You saved my project.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2020. Slightly amended version from above. In my case I needed to check for  `sel.Characters.Count <= 3`. Thanks!

```
Public Function DeleteBlankPages()
Dim i, j, notEmpty, c
Dim sel As Selection

myWordDoc.Activate

ActiveDocument.Repaginate

Set sel = ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection

j = ActiveDocument.BuiltinDocumentProperties(wdPropertyPages)

For i = j To 1 Step -1
    notEmpty = True
    sel.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=CStr(i)
    sel.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page"

    'Debug.Print "Page", i, " count", sel.Characters.Count

    If sel.Characters.Count <= 3 Then
        notEmpty = False
        For Each c In sel.Characters
            If Asc(c) > 13 Then
                ''Possibly not empty
                notEmpty = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If notEmpty = False Then
        sel.Delete
    End If
Next
```

End Function